# handlebars.js “each” loop inside another “each” loop 3

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Suppose I want to build a dynamic table. How do I run each inside each. If the only varible that represents current item is `this`.

```
   {{#each by_width}}
       {{#each by_height}}
          {{this}} // how do refer to this from the outer loop?
       {{/each}}
   {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use `../` to access the parent in a Handlebars template:

```
{{#each by_width}}
    {{#each by_height}}
       w: {{../this}}
       h: {{this}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

That of course assumes that `by_height` is inside each element of `by_width`, if they're both at the top level then you'd need another `../`:

```
{{#each by_width}}
    {{#each ../by_height}}
       w: {{../this}}
       h: {{this}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PNTXw/

Comment: And how do you get `{{@index}}` of `{{../this}}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write `{{../this}}` but `{{..this}}`.

Comment: are you sure {{..this}} working withobject keys in loop

Comment: When I wrote that, yes I was sure. But, I haven't been doing meteor for a while.