# Meteor blaze each inside each

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I've been trying to use blaze Each with a Each inside

ColA being one collection

ColB another different collection (not inside ColA)

```
{{#each colA}}
   {{#each colB}}
      {{this}} // refer the outer Loop?
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

like this guy asked on [this Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059157/handlebars-js-each-loop-inside-another-each-loop-3) but when i try that the app brokes. Seems its pretty old... 2012.

Is there an effective way to do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming

ColA has: title, author

ColB has comment, user

```
{{#each colA}}
    {{#each colB}}
        {{ ../title }} by {{ ../author }}
        {{ comment }} by {{ user }} // refer the outer Loop?
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That actually works.. thanks. But my problem was that i was using ARRAYS... seems that `{{ .. }}` is the `this` of the outer array.